# What is the implication of the word "into" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

The quote I came across was:

> Twitter’s board was negotiating with Mr. Musk **into** the early hours of Monday over his unsolicited bid to buy the company

source:

"https://www.nytimes.com/2022/04/24/technology/twitter-board-elon-musk.html"

as the preposition "into" denote movement or a rout by which somethigs may arrive at a particular destination I tend to interpret this headline as a negotiation thta began before early hours of Monday maybe even started at sunday night or dawn and prolonged until early hours of Monday. But I read the article all the way down and it gives me a feeling the meeting started itself in the early hours of Monday. Am I getting "Into" wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your first interpretation is correct. If the article later on says the negotiations started in the early hours of Monday then "into" earlier would be wrong.

Comment: I added a couple of words for clarity. I hope that's OK.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan Quite OK, That's how this site works.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct, that implies they had started negotiating on Sunday if not earlier.